# ¿ Como obtener la misma precisión entre Visual C++ y C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-c++

Estoy migrando una aplicación de **Visual C++ 2005** a **C# (vs2015)** y estoy teniendo problemas de precisión.

Si bien al principio no le presté atención, porque la diferencia aparece recién en el 6to o 7mo decimal, me está impactando en el trabajo final.

En la aplicación manejo grandes cantidades de datos a los cuales les voy aplicando operaciones matemáticas (integrales, fourirer, integralest, etc.)

Por eso manejo varios vectores multidimensionales con dimensiones de [30][100][1024].  Al comparar el output entre C# y Visual C++ terminan habiendo diferencias significativas.

Para simplificar mi problema, les muestro de forma sencilla de lo que estoy hablando:

```
//output in C#
float i = (10.0f / 65535.0f);   //0.000152590219

//output in Visual C++ 
float i = (10.0f / 65535.0f);   //0.00015259022;
```

Esa ínfinma diferencia, luego de cientos de operaciones, y de más de 3 millones de datos hace que la diferencia sea importante.

¿Hay alguna forma de decirle al compilador de C# que actué con la exacta misma precisión que Visual C++?

Comment: No conozco C#, pero ¿ has probado a usar `double` ? Dicho lenguaje lo soporta: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ahet949.aspx

Comment: -1, No le encuentro sentido a lo que preguntas. @Trauma La pregunta no trata sobre eso; la imprecisión de un número de coma flotante es diferente por compilador ... ¿Por qué querer que se comporten igual en ambos lenguajes? ¿No puede utilizar sólo un lenguaje?

Comment: Hola NaCI, entiendo lo que dices que la coma flotante es diferente por compilador.   Lo que ocurre es que estoy migrando una aplicación de Visual C++ a C# y necesito mantener los mismos outputs.

Comment: @NaCl, si fuera yo, usaría `double` (que según https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/double tiene 64 bits, mas que un `float` de 32 bits en C++), y limitaría artificialmente los dígitos al **mostrar** los resultados. **Nunca** sería igual que C++, pero la diferencia *casi*, *casi*, sería despreciable. E insisto en que no conozco C#.

Comment: @Trauma Pues claro, `double` es el tipo por defecto, más que `float` **OP** Usa double, debe de dar el resultado esperado, si no mal recuerdo, ambos cumplen con los estándares.

Comment: Hola, el problema es que estoy usando librerías externas donde solo se admiten float, no puedo usar double lamentablemente...

Comment: Hola, has analizado la posibilidad de mantener el codigo donde realizas las operaciones en un binario que luego referencies desde C#, de esa manera creo que mantendrias la misma funcionalidad que en C++ y podras usarlo en C# y en aplicaciones futuras.

Answer (score 1):

Puede usar algo como lo siguente:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // your code goes here

        float b = (10.0f/65535.0f);
        decimal t = (decimal)(10.0f/65535.0f);

        Console.WriteLine("d :" + t);
        Console.WriteLine("d :" + Math.Round(t, 11));

    }
}
```

---

Puede mirar sobre:

- [`Math.Round ();`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`Math.Ciel ();`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/1cz5da1c(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`Math.floor ();`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/k7ycc7xh(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.midpointrounding(v=vs.110).aspx)

Si lo que necesita es Math.Round();

podria usar algo asi:

```
    decimal t = (decimal)(10.0f/65535.0f);
    decimal n = Math.Round(t, 11);  
    Console.WriteLine("d :" + n);
```

---

Test Ideone.com tras su comentario:

<kbd>[Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/SviXYP)</kbd>

Comment: Hola Angel, gracias por tu respuesta.

el output usando Decimal es 0.0001525902

En Visual C++ es 0.00015259022

Está cerca pero no es igual!

Comment: @Woko deje revisar porque lo mire y era igual, quizas le deje un codigo diferente.Saludos

Comment: @Woko acabo de mirar el codigo y le deje un link a ideone, y pienso que se muestra como usted dice `0.00015259022`. Saludos

Comment: @Woko puede ser que pusiera -> `Math.Round(t, 10);` en lugar de -> `Math.Round(t, 11);` fijese 11 en lugar de 10.Saludos

Comment: Angel muchas gracias, tienes toda la razón. 
El problema es que yo necesito una forma genérica en la cual C# siempre se comporte como lo hace Visual C++. 

Y para este caso puntual, la forma que encontraste funciona, pero si el número tiene 6 decimales, o 15 o 3 necesito que siempre se comporte igual.

Answer (score 0):

[https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=net-5.0[midpointrounding][1]](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=net-5.0%5Bmidpointrounding%5D%5B1%5D)

ToPositiveInfinity  4

Modo dirigido: el número se redondea hacia arriba, con el resultado más cercano y no menor que el resultado infinitamente preciso.

```
result = Math.Round(positiveValue,MidpointRounding.ToPositiveInfinity );
```

ToPositiveInfinity  4

Modo dirigido: el número se redondea hacia arriba, con el resultado más cercano y no menor que el resultado infinitamente preciso.

Esto es lo que hace C++